# Fluent Nhibernate "invalid or incomplete configuration" when running in "WCF Test Client"

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a WCF web service website, Web service library, and a and I have a Domain project which uses Fluent nHibernate.

When I run the WCF project and run a invoke a web service it works fine, as long it's not a service that accesses the database.

If I invoke a web service that accesses the DB, I always get an error here:

```
      _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(@"Server=MYSERVER;database=MYDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=true;")

                .ShowSql()
            )
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                    .AddFromAssemblyOf<WhygoDomain.Location>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
            /* .Create(true, true)*/) 
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Which says:
**An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.**

Inner Exception says:
**A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)**

I do not get this message if I do the following:
1) Right click on the webservice.svc and copy the "view in browser" link.
2) (in the WCF test client) right click on "my service projects"-> "add service" and paste in the URL from 1) above

I have been working like this for a while, but it's a bit slower and it means I can't debug, which isn't really acceptable.

What's happening here?
It seems like a permission problem connecting to the database, but I'm new to most of this so it may be something else.

I have tried giving permission to any user I can think of to the database, but no change. What user does the WCF test client use, does anyone know?

The result of this issue is that I can't debug my web service which is a problem for me. I guess I could try attach to process or something, but this wouldn't be ideal as I have plenty of web service work on the horizon.

Comment: can you post the complete Exception (`ex.ToString()`) ?

Comment: @Firo, I have added that detail in there now.

Comment: did you try using an explicit username and password in the connection string?

Comment: @Eren Ersonmez no, do you think that will help?

Comment: well, I don't know much about NHibernate so I might be off but it could have something to do with that Trusted_Connection=true. Sure would be a quick thing to try loging in via a Sql account ( see http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Database_configuration).

Comment: @Eren Ersonmez I get the same behaviour as with integrated security. It doesn't work when I try run the default service in "WCF test client", but it does work when I right click and add the URL of the service into the test client, so I still can't debug...

Comment: actually, this probably is not a permission issue. the inner exception states it cannot connect to the sql server endpoint. it somehow cannot resolve to the correct endpoint or being blocked. how it works in one case but not the other, that beats me.  take a look at these:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186623/nhibernate-connection-string-how-to-specify-port-number-and-server-instance
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067126/problem-connecting-to-mysql-from-nhibernate

Answer (score 1):

check that your service in running in IIS with full trust. OLEDB or ODBC works only in full trust under IIS even though, if you can modify the file web_mediumtrust.config in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config, you can add in the SecurityClasses section:

```
<SecurityClass Name="OleDbPermission" Description="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
<SecurityClass Name="OdbcPermission" Description="System.Data.OleDb.OdbcPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the connection string set to windows authentication? If so set it to SQL Server Authentication and see if it still works testing it locally. Also check that the database is setup to use both Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication.